# Python recursion function - what is going on here?

Tags: python, function, recursion, factorial

I have a simple factorial function written in python with a bunch of debug embedded to aid my understanding of what is going on. However, the output has confused me even more. Can anyone help me understand? (BTW, in case there was a print output timing issue, I ran it several times but got exactly the same output.)

recursive_function.py

```
def recursive(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  print ('n : {}'.format(n))
  print ('recursive return value is: {}'.format(n*recursive(n-1)))
  return n*recursive(n-1)

x = recursive(5)
print('***** End result is: {}'.format(x))
```

(with line numbers)

```
1   n : 5
2   n : 4
3   n : 3
4   n : 2
5   recursive return value is: 2
6   recursive return value is: 6
7   n : 2
8   recursive return value is: 2
9   recursive return value is: 24
10  n : 3
11  n : 2
12  recursive return value is: 2
13  recursive return value is: 6
14  n : 2
15  recursive return value is: 2
16  recursive return value is: 120
17  n : 4
18  n : 3
19  n : 2
20  recursive return value is: 2
21  recursive return value is: 6
22  n : 2
23  recursive return value is: 2
24  recursive return value is: 24
25  n : 3
26  n : 2
27  recursive return value is: 2
28  recursive return value is: 6
29  n : 2
30  recursive return value is: 2
31  ***** End result is: 120
```

(cleaner output without line numbers)

```
n : 5
n : 4
n : 3
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 6
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 24
n : 3
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 6
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 120
n : 4
n : 3
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 6
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 24
n : 3
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
recursive return value is: 6
n : 2
recursive return value is: 2
***** End result is: 120
```

Comment: One thing that would finitely help would be to not do recursion twice! In your 2nd print you do `n*recursive(n-1)` which actually calls the same method and messes up the output! Instead save the result and the print/return it: `res = n*recursive(n-1); print(f"Recursion result {res}"); return res` (<--pseudo code not python)

Comment: What is your question? Asking "why does this behave the way it does" does not ask anything, really. This is doing what it does. What do you not understand?

Comment: "urban , you are right, I'm totally confusing myself. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The function takes a number and calculates the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) result.

So, for the value of `5` the result is `5 * 4 * 3 * 2` which is `120`.

It makes sense to make that function a recursive one, because the factorial of 5 is 5 times the factorial of 4, the factorial of 4 is 4 times the factorial of 3 and so on. In the case that the function gets called with `n = 1`, the factorial is simply returned as `1` and the recursion can stop.

Consider this to be the actual algorithm running here:

1. factorial of 5 = 5 * factorial of 4
2. factorial of 4 = 4 * factorial of 3
3. factorial of 3 = 3 * factorial of 2
4. factorial of 2 = 2 * factorial of 1
5. factorial of 1 = 1

Answer (score 3):

A version that might help:

```
def recursive(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  print ('n : {}'.format(n))
  res = recursive(n-1)
  print ('return value is: {} (n={} * recursive({})={})'.format(n*res, n, n-1, res))
  return res * n

x = recursive(5)
print('***** End result is: {}'.format(x))
```

Changes:

- Do not do recursive call twice
- Added some more debug output in the prints

Output:

```
n : 5
n : 4
n : 3
n : 2
return value is: 2 (n=2 * recursive(1)=1)
return value is: 6 (n=3 * recursive(2)=2)
return value is: 24 (n=4 * recursive(3)=6)
return value is: 120 (n=5 * recursive(4)=24)
***** End result is: 120
```

This is a very simple case, however, complex recursive methods can confuse anyone. I have found that tabbing each call (and its print messages) helps me understand what is happening. To do this you just need to pass down the recursion level (`l`) in each call:

```
def recursive(n, l=0):
  # l is the recurcion level
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  print ('{} n : {}'.format(l * "  ", n))
  res = recursive(n-1, l + 1)
  print ('{} return value is: {} (n={} * recursive({})={})'.format(
    l * "  ", n * res, n, n-1, res)
  )
  return res*n
```

This now formats things a little bit:

```
 n : 5
   n : 4
     n : 3
       n : 2
       return value is: 2 (n=2 * recursive(1)=1)
     return value is: 6 (n=3 * recursive(2)=2)
   return value is: 24 (n=4 * recursive(3)=6)
 return value is: 120 (n=5 * recursive(4)=24)
***** End result is: 120
```

Comment: Updated answer (sry forgot to remove double call!)

Comment: Your first example still has the double call to recursion

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not really well fitted for a recursive begginer, so I attached here another code that outputs the same values as yours, but its easier to understand.

```py
def recur(n):  
   if n == 1:  
       return n  
   else:  
       return n*recur(n-1)

num = int(input("Enter a number: ")) 

if num < 0:  
   print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")  

elif num == 0:  
   print("The factorial of 0 is 1")  

else:  
   print("The factorial of",num,"is",recur(num))
```

The `recur` function takes as input a natural number n. Now if n = 1, that means 1! = 1, which should be the output, no big deal.
But otherwise the function will return your number n*recur(n-1).
Example :

```py
----Take n = 4
         n = 1 -> false
         Now return (4) *recur(3)
                              (3) * recur(2)
                                         (2) * recur(1)
                                                    Now n = 1 and returns (1)
```

All the numbers in brackets, (), will be added to the overall product, so 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24. It is called recursive not because it calls itself, but because it starts backwards :))
Hope I lightened you a little bit!!

Extra Tip :

```py
if n == 1:
   return n
```

Here you can replace `return n` with `return 1`, will have the same output!

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example of a recursive function to find the factorial of an integer.

```
def calc_factorial(x):
    """This is a recursive function
    to find the factorial of an integer"""

    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (x * calc_factorial(x-1))

num = 4
print("The factorial of", num, "is", calc_factorial(num))
```

the above example, `calc_factorial()` is a recursive function as it calls itself.

When we call this function with a positive integer, it will recursively call itself by decreasing the number.

Each function calls multiples the number with the factorial of number **1** until the number is equal to one. This recursive call can be explained in the following steps.

```
calc_factorial(4)              # 1st call with 4
4 * calc_factorial(3)          # 2nd call with 3
4 * 3 * calc_factorial(2)      # 3rd call with 2
4 * 3 * 2 * calc_factorial(1)  # 4th call with 1
4 * 3 * 2 * 1                  # return from 4th call as number=1
4 * 3 * 2                      # return from 3rd call
4 * 6                          # return from 2nd call
24                             # return from 1st call
```

Our recursion ends when the number reduces to 1. This is called the base condition.

Every recursive function must have a base condition that stops the recursion or else the function calls itself infinitely.

#### Another example

A recursive function generally has two components:

- The base case is a condition that determines when the recursive function should stop
- The call to itself
  Here is an example to demonstrate both components:

```
# Assume that remaining is a positive integer

    def hi_recursive(remaining):
        # The base case
        if remaining == 0:
            return
        print('hi')
    
        # Call to function, with a reduced remaining count
        hi_recursive(remaining - 1)
```

The **base case** for us is if the remaining variable is equal to `0` i.e. how many remaining "hi" strings we must print. The function simply returns.

After the print statement, we call **`hi_recursive`** again but with a reduced remaining value. This is important! If we do not decrease the value of remaining the function will run indefinitely. Generally, when a recursive function calls itself the parameters are changed to be closer to the base case.

Let's visualize how it works when we **`call hi_recursive(3)`**:

[image]

After the function prints '**`hi`**', it calls itself with a lower value for remaining until it reaches `0`. At zero, the function returns to where it was called in **`hi_recursive(1)`**, which returns to where it was called in **`hi_recursive(2)`** and that ultimately returns to where it was called in **`hi_recursive(3)`**.